# 3D roof polygon creation from polylines in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, photogrammetry

I am Working in ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop, and I would like to create roof polygons from lines, the lines are captured with photogrammetry technique.

As per my requirement I have found tool "3D Building Generator Tool", but tool is based on VBA language.

Can anyone guide me in arcgis 10.1 to create Buildings roof polygon using with Arctoolbox or is there any alternative process?

Comment: Please find following link. http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/38957-3D-Building-Generator-Toolbar

Comment: Thanks, I have saw that method, but now in my arcgis 10.1 not able to use VBA Tools.I am expecting alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

Multipatch feature are supported 3D building so you can try to use this method.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q80000007n000000

Comment: This is for footprints.I am expecting roof surface.the roof surface not only flat roof it maybe cone, pyramid, dome and slope roof.